# Adding a value when a checkbox is checked

Tags: android, firebase, checkbox

I want to retrieve the number of checkboxes checked, here is my try.

```
    private int checkCheckBoxes(int total) {
            View habitosView = (LayoutInflater.from(mContext)).inflate(R.layout.habitos_list_row, null);
            CheckBox CB1 = habitosView.findViewById(R.id.CBdia1);
            CheckBox CB2 = habitosView.findViewById(R.id.CBdia2);
            CheckBox CB3 = habitosView.findViewById(R.id.CBdia3);
            CheckBox CB4 = habitosView.findViewById(R.id.CBdia4);
            CheckBox CB5 = habitosView.findViewById(R.id.CBdia5);
            CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[5];
            checkBoxes[0] = CB1;
            checkBoxes[1] = CB2;
            checkBoxes[2] = CB3;
            checkBoxes[3] = CB4;
            checkBoxes[4] = CB5;
            int habitosTotal = total;
            for (int x=0; x<5; x++){
                if(checkBoxes[x].isChecked()){
                    habitosTotal = habitosTotal +  1;
                }
            }
            Log.d("Habitos total" , habitosTotal+"");
            return habitosTotal;

    };
```

**And for the OnClick of the view I have this**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
        holder.nombre.setText(mHabitosList.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.habitosCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int total = mHabitosList.get(position).getTotal();
                checkCheckBoxes(total);
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                FragmentHabitos fragmentHabitos= new FragmentHabitos();
                fragmentHabitos.setArguments(args);
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentHabitos)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

Its returning 0 no matter what, can someone point me out the error. I could not find it.

Comment: I don't see where you're sending the total number of checkbox to the destination Fragment

Comment: My bad, I just want to add to the int **total** of the Object **Habitos** the number of CheckBoxes checked

Answer (score 1):

You should use setOnCheckedChangeListener.

Sample:

```
chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
 CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()){
            case R.id.checkbox1:
                if(isChecked)
                    //increment checked total
                else
                    //dercrement checked total
                break;
            case R.id.checkBox2:
                if(isChecked)
                   //increment checked total
                else
                  //decrement checked total
                break;


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Whats does the chk stands for?

Comment: my idea is to have checkbox view(chk) fetched from your MyViewHolder class.

Answer (score 0):

I have it in one of my app.

```
 btnCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(rb1.isChecked()){
                        dadosresponsavel = new Dadosresponsavel();
                        dadosresponsavel.setNome(tNome.getText().toString().trim());
                        dadosresponsavel.setCidade(tCidade.getText().toString().trim());
                        dadosresponsavel.setTelefone(tTelefone.getText().toString().trim());
                        dadosresponsavel.setEmail(useremail.getText().toString().trim());
                        dadosresponsavel.setSenha(usersenha.getText().toString().trim());
                        dadosresponsavel.isTipoDeCadastro();
                        cadastrarResponsavel();
                    }
                    else
                    if(rb2.isChecked()){
                        Dadosmotorista = new Dadosmotorista();
                        Dadosmotorista.setNome(tNome.getText().toString().trim());
                        Dadosmotorista.setCidade(tCidade.getText().toString().trim());
                        Dadosmotorista.setTelefone(tTelefone.getText().toString().trim());
                        Dadosmotorista.setEmail(useremail.getText().toString().trim());
                        Dadosmotorista.setSenha(usersenha.getText().toString().trim());
                        Dadosmotorista.isTipoDeCadastro();
                        cadastrarMotorista();
                    }
                }
            });
```